# Minimal polynomial linear operator $A$ in finite dimension complex vector space ptoblem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ m_{A} ( \lambda) = (\lambda -2)^2$  be a minimal polynomial of linear operator $A$ in finite dimension complex  vector space. Find the mimimal polynomial of the operator $A^2$ .
This is what I tried: 
There exists a vector v which is not zero so that
$ Av=2v$ . Then we have $  A^2(v)=A(2v)=2A(v)=4v$. So $\lambda -4 $ is a factor in the minimal polynomial of $A^2$ . But how do I know if there are any other factors?
I got the same result when I tried looking at the determinants. From $ (A-2)^2 =0$ I got $A^2= 4A-4I$ and then I looked at the deterimants minus $\lambda I $ but got nowhere.

Comment: Possibly relevant fact: If $A,B$ are two commuting operators then every eigenspace of $A$ is an eigenspace of $B$, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a good start; the fact that $A^2=4A-4I$ implies that
$$(A^2+4I)^2-16(A^2+4I)+64I=(4A)^2-16(4A)+64I=16(A^2-4A+4I)=0,$$
and so the minimal polynomial of $A^2$ divides
$$(\lambda+4)^2-16(\lambda+4)+64=((\lambda+4)-8)^2=(\lambda-4)^2,$$
hence there are no other factors.